# cvc-complex-type.2.1: Element 'soap:address'... WSDL Error in Eclipse

Tags: wsdl

I am integrating my exsting workspace in Eclipse 3.6. This workspace was originally created using BEA Workshop 10.3 and weblogic 9.2 server and was working fine. Now I am using JDK 6 and weblogic 10.3.4 server along with Eclipse. But when I imported this workspace in Ecipse, I am getting below error:

Error 1: Description Resource Path Location Type 
cvc-complex-type.2.1: Element 'soap:address' must have no character or element information item [children], because the type's content type is empty.

Error 2: Description Resource Path Location Type 
cvc-complex-type.2.1: Element 'soap:binding' must have no character or element information item [children], because the type's content type is empty.

Error 3: Description Resource Path Location Type 
The input element is referencing an undefined message 'getTaskByIDRequestMsg'. Check that the message name and namespace are correct and that the message has been defined. AppComponent1INFExport_listComponent1INFHttpService.wsdl /appWebServiceClient/src/myapp/list_new line 2 WSDL Problem

Starting part of one of my WSDL file is :

I am unable to figure out the cause of the errors. Can anybody please help me in this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this problem and found the solution here: http://ebxml.xml.org/node/565

From that link, here's the "incorrect" way of doing things:

```
<soap:body namespace="urn:12345"  use="iteral"> <!-- this is not empty! --> </soap:body>
```

versus the correct way:

```
<soap:body namespace="urn:12345" use="literal"/>
```

Make the change and your errors should disappear!